# Retornar valor com XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

```
     dataPacket: function(type){
        aTurn.packet = new XMLHttpRequest();
        aTurn.packet.open('GET', 'teste.php', true);
        aTurn.packet.send();

        aTurn.packet.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(aTurn.packet.readyState == 4 && aTurn.packet.status == 200){
                data = JSON.parse(aTurn.packet.response);
                return data.current;
            }
        }
    },
```

Estou usando essa função para obter valores de um arquivo json. Porém, quando acionada gostaria que retornasse o valor data, assim como fiz no exemplo, porém retorna undefined, o que posso fazer?

Seria possível usar o parâmetro type de dataPacket() para definir o valor final, por exemplo: dataPacket('teste') retornaria o data.teste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode retornar um valor de uma funçào assincrona, você poderá utilizar uma função de callback ou uma Promise.

Ex callback:

```
dataPacket: function(type, callback){
        aTurn.packet = new XMLHttpRequest();
        aTurn.packet.open('GET', 'teste.php', true);

        aTurn.packet.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(aTurn.packet.readyState == 4 && aTurn.packet.status == 200){
                data = JSON.parse(aTurn.packet.response);

                // Chamada do callback
                if( typeof callback == 'function' ) {
                    callback(data);

                    // Ou caso, queira pegar o valor de type
                    callback(data[type]) 
                }
            }
        }

        aTurn.packet.send();
    },
```

Chamada

```
dataPacket('teste', function(resultado){
   console.log(resultado);
})
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem amigo, porém acontece conflito com algumas funções que eu estou utlizando. Seria possível retornar um valor chamando a função nesse estilo: aTurn.dataPacket('teste')? Ou algo do tipo que não utilize função no retorno.

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma Promise.  Ex: ` dataPacket: function(type){ return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ) {  `...seu código, no lugar de `callback(data);` vai `resolve(data);` ...resto do código, assim você chamaria  a função da seguinte forma:  `aTurn.dataPacket('teste').then(function(resultado){ //manipulação do resultado })` 

[O que é Promise??](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Exemplos)

Comment: Mas assim continuaria chamando a o resultado com uma função, é isso que quero driblar.

Comment: Se não for possível utilizando XMLHttpRequest seria possível utilizar $.ajax ou $.post? Eu tentei utilizar ajax com o async false, funcionou, porém está em estado deprecated.

Comment: Qualquer uma destas opções não tem um retorno, só por uma função de callback ou Promise mesmo.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado.